# running sample typeahead in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

i just started using bootstrap and the following jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nt3qsjbx/ contains the sample code for typeahead. 
I am not sure which this is not working!!

```
$('#country_v1-query').typeahead({
    order: "desc",
    source: {
        data: [
            "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda",
            "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh",
            "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia",
            "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burma",
            "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Central African Republic", "Chad",
            "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo, Democratic Republic", "Congo, Republic of the"... ]});
```

Comment: I have included jquery and bootstrap library. Is it not enought?

Comment: Depending on what version of Bootstrap you're using, you might need the actual typeahead library, which is separate.

Comment: Yeah - looks like it was dropped in Bootstrap 3 - may checkout https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Twitter Typeahead](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/)

It's quite easy to use and straight forward.

Here is a good example of how to use it: https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/